# Identify Google API Key given client_id + client_secret

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-iam

I work in an ecosystem with a million Google projects, services, and accounts. I have a Google Calendar API client_id and client_secret, and I'd like to upgrade the billing on that API account.

Is there a way for me to search for the API credentials and update the billing given just the client_id and client_secret? We're getting rate limited and would like to upgrade the billing to get these events shipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Client ID contains the project number, which will be the first set of numbers up to the hyphen.

Example:

```
889131808289-j4ebh96l7ltnnblk14jc7v7r06kf03rl.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

The project number is `889131808289`.

Use the command `gcloud projects describe PROJECT_NUMBER` to get details on the project.

Example:

```
gcloud projects describe 889131808289
```

Output:

```
createTime: '2018-10-13T04:30:17.002Z'
labels:
  firebase: enabled
lifecycleState: ACTIVE
name: Development
parent:
  id: '834075312893'
  type: folder
projectId: development-304587
projectNumber: '889131808289'
```

Note: For security, the secrets above are not valid values.

Once you have the Project ID, you can then match the project to the corresponding billing account by a manual process.  You can also use the Google Cloud Console GUI to easily look up the billing account for a project [link](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/verify-billing-enabled) and [link](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/find-billing-account-id).

When I have a large number of billing accounts and projects, I create a table manually listing all billing accounts and their projects. A simple Python program can parse the JSON and create a searchable table:

```
gcloud billing accounts list --format=json

gcloud billing projects list --billing-account=0101A4-9F1278-8A34FF --format=json
```

The correct IAM roles to access this level of project and billing information are required on your IAM principal.

**For more information:**

[gcloud projects describe](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/describe)

[gcloud billing projects](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/billing/projects)

[Find a Cloud Billing Account ID](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/find-billing-account-id)

[Check if billing is enabled on a project](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/verify-billing-enabled#confirm_billing_is_enabled_on_a_project)